# Error to build opencv on Ubuntu 14.04 [cannot find -lstdc++]

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, clang++

I'm new to build and install opencv on my Ubuntu 14.04.

I follow [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) to do it.

After typing cmake command, I encounter some errors as follows.
I google some solutions and try to reinstall some packages, ex:**gcc**.

Still can not work...  :(

for `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++` problem, anyone has ideas?

thank you :)

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.4.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/clang++" is not able to compile a simple test
program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: 
/home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3807027872/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/build.make
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/build



make[1]: Entering directory
  `/home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
  /home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles
  1

  Building CXX object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o

  /usr/bin/clang++ -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c
  /home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx


  Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec3807027872

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /usr/bin/clang++
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3807027872.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o
  cmTryCompileExec3807027872 -rdynamic

  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)

  make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3807027872] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  `/home/eric/program_files/OpenCV/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3807027872/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:88 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

or

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
```